# facing problem in panda column modification

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a weird scenario.
I have a data frame with having 3 largest scores for unique row like this:

```
id   rid   code  score
1    9    67    43
1    8    87    22 
1    4    32    20
2    3    56    43
3    10.  22    100
3.   5    67.    50
```

Here  id column is same but row wise it is different.
I want to make my data frame like this:

```
id   first_code  second_code    third_code
1     67          87            32
2.    56.         none.         none
3     22.         67.           none
```

So I have made my dataframe which is showing highest top 3 scores. If there is not top 3 value I am taking top 2 or the only value which is the score. So depending on score value, I want to re-arrange the code column into three different columns as example first_code is representing the highest_score, second_score is representing second-highest, third_code is representing the third highest value. If not found then I will make those blanks.

Kindly help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, create `MultiIndex` and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['id',df.groupby('id').cumcount()])['code'].unstack()
df.columns=['first_code', 'second_code', 'third_code']
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
    id  first_code  second_code  third_code
0  1.0        67.0         87.0        32.0
1  2.0        56.0          NaN         NaN
2  3.0        22.0         67.0         NaN
```

Btw, `cumcount` should be used also in previous code for filter top3 values.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I didn't know about this approach.  I am learning ;)